# Is there any way you can import local procs from other files in the same directory?

Tags: nim-lang

If you have 2 Python files in the same directory, you can do the following:

---

*something.py*

```
def returnSomething():
    return True
```

index.py

```
from something import returnSomething

test=returnSomething()
```

---

Can something similar be done in Nim by calling their `proc`s?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can, you just need to export the proc by adding `*` (the export marker) after the name of it - https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#procedures-export-marker :)

```
# something.nim
proc returnSomething*(): bool = 
  result = true
```

```
# index.nim
import something

test = returnSomething()
```

You can also replace `import something` with `from something import returnSomething`, but it's a personal preference.

I think it might be good for you to read https://narimiran.github.io/nim-basics/ which covers most of Nim basics :)